# Include a table as label in pgfplots

Tags: tables, pgfplots

I would like to have as a `symbolic x coordinate` a `tabular`. Is this possible? Below is a MWE that has all the required elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
ybar, 
symbolic x coords={A,B,C}, 
xtick=data,
]    
\addplot coordinates {(A,0.16)(B,0.10)(C,0.07)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Where label A is to be \begin{tabular}{r}1\\2\\3\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `xticklabels={\begin{tabular}{r}1\\2\\3\end{tabular},B,C},` in the `axis` options. Unfortunately, specifying a single tick mark text manually necessitates setting them all manually (hence the `,B,C` required).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tick label can contain anything that's allowed inside a Tikz `node`, with the *caveat* that if it contains comma(s), it must be protected with curly braces. Use

```
 xticklabels={\begin{tabular}{r}1\\2\\3\end{tabular},B,C},
```

in the `axis` options. The `,B,C` is required because if one tick label text is manually specified, all of them need to be manually specified.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
ybar, 
symbolic x coords={A,B,C}, 
xticklabels={\begin{tabular}{r}1\\2\\3\end{tabular},B,C},
xtick=data,
]    
\addplot coordinates {(A,0.16)(B,0.10)(C,0.07)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]